# could not find implicit value for parameter enc: CsvEncoder[Shape]

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to understand coproduct of shapeless and have following example, that does not work:

```
import shapeless.{HList, ::, HNil}
import shapeless.Generic
import shapeless.{Coproduct, :+:, CNil, Inl, Inr}

trait CsvEncoder[A] {
  def encode(value: A): List[String]
}


sealed trait Shape

final case class Rectangle(width: Double, height: Double) extends Shape

final case class Circle(radius: Double) extends Shape

object CsvEncoder {

  def createEncoder[A](func: A => List[String]): CsvEncoder[A] = {
    new CsvEncoder[A] {
      override def encode(value: A): List[String] = func(value)
    }
  }

  implicit val booleanEncoder: CsvEncoder[Boolean] =
    createEncoder(value => if (value) List("yes") else List("no"))

  implicit val intEncoder: CsvEncoder[Int] =
    createEncoder(value => List(value.toString))

  implicit val stringEncoder: CsvEncoder[String] =
    createEncoder(value => List(value))

  implicit val doubleEncoder: CsvEncoder[Double] =
    createEncoder(value => List(value.toString))


  def apply[A](implicit enc: CsvEncoder[A]): CsvEncoder[A] = enc

  implicit val cnilEncoder: CsvEncoder[CNil] =
    createEncoder(cnil => throw new Exception("Inconceivable!"))

  implicit def coproductEncoder[H, T <: Coproduct](
                                                    implicit
                                                    hEncoder: CsvEncoder[H],
                                                    tEncoder: CsvEncoder[T]
                                                  ): CsvEncoder[H :+: T] = createEncoder {
    case Inl(h) => hEncoder.encode(h)
    case Inr(t) => tEncoder.encode(t)
  }

  def writeCsv[A](values: List[A])(implicit enc: CsvEncoder[A]): String =
    values.map(value => enc.encode(value).mkString(",")).mkString("\n")


}

object Main {


  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("----------------------------------------------------------")
    val shapes: List[Shape] = List(
      Rectangle(3.0, 4.0),
      Circle(1.0)
    )
    println(CsvEncoder.writeCsv(shapes))

  }

}
```

The compiler complains:

```
Error:(162, 32) could not find implicit value for parameter enc: CsvEncoder[Shape]
    println(CsvEncoder.writeCsv(shapes))
Error:(162, 32) not enough arguments for method writeCsv: (implicit enc: CsvEncoder[Shape])String.
Unspecified value parameter enc.
    println(CsvEncoder.writeCsv(shapes))
```

Do I have create an instance of `CsvEncoder` for `Shape`? Shapeless should care it for me, or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend re/reading [The Type Astronaut's Guide to Shapeless Book](https://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/), it really is an amazing book. It seems the code you have posted is partly from there.

---

The CSV Encoder example uses `Employee`, and writes the `CsvEncoder` by hand (page 23):

```
implicit val iceCreamEncoder: CsvEncoder[IceCream] =
  new CsvEncoder[IceCream] {
    def encode(i: IceCream): List[String] =
      List(
        i.name,
        i.numCherries.toString,
        if(i.inCone) "yes" else "no"
      )
  }
```

If you do *not* want to have to write all this by hand, you're gonna need a bit more boilerplate.

---

This is described in 3.2.1 of the book, around page 27:

```
import shapeless.{HList, ::, HNil}
implicit val hnilEncoder: CsvEncoder[HNil] =
  createEncoder(hnil => Nil)
implicit def hlistEncoder[H, T <: HList](
  implicit
  hEncoder: CsvEncoder[H],
  tEncoder: CsvEncoder[T]
): CsvEncoder[H :: T] =
  createEncoder {
    case h :: t =>
      hEncoder.encode(h) ++ tEncoder.encode(t)
  }
```

We have the recursion case, `hlistEncoder` (that returns `CsvEncoder[H :: T]`), that takes the head and the tail, and the base case encoder, `hnilEncoder` (that returns `CsvEncoder[HNil]`, because a HList always has a `HNil` at its end, like every other linked list).

This, however, is enough to CSV-encode any HList, but a `Rectangle` isn't a `HList`! You need to use a `Generic` to convert back-and-forth. This is explained in 3.2.2 of the book, right after the previous part (I converted the code to use `Generic.Aux`, which is one of the most important tools of shapeless):

```
implicit def genericEncoder[A, R](
  implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[A, R],
  enc: CsvEncoder[R]
): CsvEncoder[A] =
  createEncoder(a => enc.encode(gen.to(a)))
```

The `gen.to` converts `a` (say `Rectangle`) to an HList (so, `Double :: Double :: HNil`, and encodes that.
It also converts `Shape` to `Rectangle :+: Circle :+: CNil`, so your `Main` works as-is :).

Comment: This solution can't work out any longer. I just tried! Would you plz check out again? My scala version is 2.13.6 and my shapeless is ""com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3""